# Remove empty/newline from an output file

Tags: linux, diff, tr

How do I remove empty lines from an output file so I can use diff to compare a reference file to my output file?

I found a post about removing new lines such as:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input_filename > out
```

So I tried something like

```
tr '\n\n' '\n' < input_filename > out
```

But it does seems to do anything.

How do I go from

```
1 <somecode>
2 <somecode>
3 
4 <somecode>
5 <somecode>
6 <somecode>
7 <somecode>
8 
9 <somecode>
```

to

```
1 <somecode>
2 <somecode>
3 <somecode>
4 <somecode>
5 <somecode>
6 <somecode>
7 <somecode>
8
9
```

Also the reference output is not

```
\n\n
```

but rather

```
\n<sometabs>\n
```

Which makes

```
tr -s '\n' < input > output
```

not stripping all the consecutive newlines.

Comment: An easier alternative may just be to tell `diff` to ignore whitespace differences with the `-w` option or to ignore changes blank line differences with the `-B` option.

Comment: Then -b option did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` command:

```
 cat input_filename | sed '/^$/d' > out
```

That delete all line that match expression `^$` (that means that are empty)

Comment: you can use -i option so you don't have to use cat